# Selecting months during PDF export with form submit.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2 application with a model called Mileages. I have added a PDF output of the mileages index action using Prawn PDF.

The mileages_controller's index action looks like this:

```
def index
    @mileages = Mileage.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @mileages_months = Mileage.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id).group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @mileages }
      format.pdf do
            pdf = MileagePdf.new(@mileages, view_context)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "mileages_report.pdf",
                                  type: "application/pdf",
                                  disposition: "inline"
          end
    end
  end
```

What I would like to do, is have a link on the index view to the PDF version but alongside would be a start date and an end date. The PDF would then only show the mileage entries between those two dates.

The PDF link would simply be `<%= link_to "Mileage Report (PDF)", mileages_path(@mileages, format: "pdf") %>`

The activerecord filter would, presumably, be something like this:

```
@mileages = Milage.where(:date => ??..??)
```

I am unsure how to tie the above to the date inputs. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a kind of form submit since you have dates.

```
 <%= form_tag(mileages_path(format: :pdf), method: :get) do -%>
    <%= date_select("mileage_start", "date",  order: [:year,:month,:day])%>
    <%= date_select("mileage_end", "date",  order: [:year,:month,:day])%>
    <%= submit_tag %>
  <%end%>
```

**`UPDATED with Final answer from chat`**

```
  def index 
    start_date = params[:mileage_start] 
    end_date = params[:mileage_end] 
    if start_date && end_date 
      dates = get_start_and_end_date(start_date,end_date) 
      @mileages_pdf = Mileage.where(date: dates[:start_date]..dates[:end_date]) 
   end 

    respond_to do |format|
     # format.html # index.html.erb
     # format.json { render json: @mileages }
      format.pdf do
        pdf = MileagePdf.new(@mileages_pdf, view_context)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "mileages_report.pdf",
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: "inline"
      end
    end   
  end 

  def get_start_and_end_date(start_date,end_date) 
    hsh = {} 
    hsh[:start_date] = build_date(start_date)
    hsh[:end_date] = build_date(end_date)
    hsh 
  end

  def build_date(hsh)
    DateTime.new(hsh["date(1i)"].to_i,hsh["date(2i)"].to_i,hsh["date(3i)"].to_i)
  end
```

This way you can capture the date from params and format it in the way you want and place it in your query.

Comment: What would the controller code be though? `Milage.where(:date => #{start}..#{end})`?

Comment: If I understand correctly then the lower of the code examples should go in my index method - but I get `undefined method `values' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: sorry, my bad.. i missed `if date_hsh` updated the `date_formatter` method

Comment: I'm a little confused by the mix of `start_date` and `mileage_start`. Also how do I pull those params into the controller query?

Comment: @dannymcc, don't get confused by mileage_start, it's just a name given to select field which comes with date select.  I have updated the controller with the way you can check what params comes from the form submit.  I hope this will help you understand how date comes inside controller as params.  `date_formatter` method is just formatting those params

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32845/discussion-between-ankitg-and-dannymcc)